# XSL FO Cover page in PDF-readers double page view

Tags: xslt, xsl-fo, apache-fop

Is there a way to mark the title page as such in xsl fo? When I open my document in the pdf reader in double page mode I would like to see the cover page alone first and then the content pages next to each other.
so:

```
page 1 : cover -> single view
Page 2 : Content -> double view left side
Page 3 : Content -> double view right side
```

Instead, I'm currently having

```
Page 1 : cover -> double view left side
Page 2 : Content -> double view right side
Page 3 : Content -> double view left side
```

etc.

There must be an attribute for this, or not?
I am using Apache FOP v2.3

Answer (score 1):

You can set custom PDF properties using FOP (see https://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/2.4/output.html#custom-document-properties), but I can't see how to influence the PDF display.

If you were using AH Formatter, you'd use `axf:document-info` (see https://www.antenna.co.jp/AHF/help/en/ahf-ext.html#axf.document-info), but I can't see an equivalent for FOP in https://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/2.4/extensions.html.

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer. Hmm but i guess there is also no way to influence it over the PDF properties?!? I should really switch over to Antenna House formatter :D

Comment: Someone who uses FOP day-to-day may have a better answer. Everyone who can should switch over to Antenna House Formatter for its extra features, and that's both my biased and my unbiased opinions.

Answer (score 0):

Control of the PDF view is the readers prerogative, thus in the majority of cases is dependant on user settings. The viewer can place page 2 above page 1 or 3 & 4 above 1 & 2 if so designed, Here more conventionaly the user sets cover and spreads as you wish.

[image]

[image]

[image]